# sort with current or previous state

Tags: sorting, react-native, state

Is there a reason to use prevState as follows:

```
sort=()=>{
 this.setState(prevState =>({contacts: [...prevState.contacts].sort(compareNames)}))
}
```

or is it ok to just use:

```
sort=()=>{
  this.setState({contacts: [...this.state.contacts].sort(compareNames)})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the react documentation for [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

> React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for
>   performance.
>
> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>
> ```
> // Wrong
> this.setState({
>   counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
> });
>
> // Correct
> this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
>   counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
> }));
> ```